# Problems with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and Maximus

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I'm currently running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and I also installed Maximus because I greatly value every square inch of window space (I'm greedy like that). My issue is anytime a window is maximized (whether a new window opens maximized, or if I maximize it myself), the system doesn't load it properly so I have to press alt+f2, type in r, hit enter (shell reload) and it fixes it. While this works, it's annoying and I'd really like to have it fixed.

The settings I have, if this helps, were edited in gconf-editor. I have no_maximize set to true, and undecorate set to true. It makes no difference if I change no_maximize back to false.

Comment: Which version of Gnome are you using? [This](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/) extension may work (leave a review if it does).

Comment: I'm running Gnome 3.10.4. When I installed Ubuntu 14.04, I just installed the Gnome version.

Also, I'll try the extension. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet! It worked! Thanks so much. Guess I better make an account to review this! :-) Now how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :-( Sorry!

Comment: You should be able to accept answers :D http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers You just need to click the greyed out tick icon below the upvote downvote buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Maximus Two](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/) extension - this is based on the [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) extension, and removes the title bar to maximise screen space.

Here is a before/after screenshot:
[image]